# How can I move all changes in a file to a new branch?

Tags: git, branch

This is an issue I often run into and I wonder if there is a handy solution.

Say I work on a branch, and several commits later, a fix here, a change there, suddenly this branch affects more files than I planned to. Sometimes some of them have nothing to do with each other.
I would like to take all changes made to one or more files, and move or copy them to another branch.

Cherry-picking commits is not an option since each commit may have affected several files.

Example:

> Commit 1 - changes to foo. Created taz.
>
> Commit 2 - changes to bar, taz.
>
> Commit 3 - changes to foo, bar.
>
> Commit 4 - changes to taz.

At this point, realize `bar` has nothing to do with this branch, so I'd like to create a new branch with all the changes made to `bar` only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Define *easily*, because it will *definitely* require some work as git can't possibly guess the parts related to bar.... so, you could do this:

```
git checkout -b bar main
git cherry-pick --no-commit <id-commit-2> # apply first commit of bar
# now, you need to surgically remove all changes related to taz
# if it's a directory of its own, it's simple: git checkout HEAD -- directory-of-taz
# if it's intertwined in the files, then you need to edit them
# when you only have stuff related to bar left over in the project:
git add . # if there's anything left outside of the index, that is
git cherry-pick --continue
git cherry-pick --no-commit <id-commit-3>
# same thing
```

It could also be done with an interactive rebase, but create the branch before you start playing games:

```
git checkout -b bar main
git rebase -i <id-commit-1> # it has to be the commit _previous_ of the first commit you want to see in the final branch
# you get a list with 3 commits, you set the first 2 commits to to 'e' or 'edit'
# you drop the last one
# save and exit
# rebase will stop right after applying the second commit, first one won't be applied
# then you edit the files so that changes related to taz are gone
git add .
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
# remove all foo changes
git add .
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

And you are done.... now you have to clean up that from the original branch, right? You could pull that off by doing rebases and *reverting* (by editing the right commit on each rebase) what you have in `bar`, then `bar~1` going backwards one rebase at a time... that is to minimize having to deal with conflicts... if you wanted to do that in a single rebase, once you take advantage of the oldest commit applied in `bar` branch that you revert during the rebase, you will face conflicts in every commit that dealt with `bar` because those changes will be gone as the rebase progresses.